# Rejected edit on an out-of-date answer

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

So, there's a answer which I had upvoted quite some time ago that is now out of date. Since almost no one is currently paying attention to it, and I'd like to reverse my upvote to a downvote, I suggested an edit to highlight the parts that were out of date. It should also be noted that this answer is the top-voted answer for the question.

The review is [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/184594). Now, I understand the edit rejection reasons. But, the answerer hasn't been online since [he or she](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/47161/dazalas) posted that answer, and I'm still stuck in being unable to reverse my vote. I could update the answer to make it more accurate again, but I would be completely changing it, which is it's own reason for rejection. What are my options?

Comment: Strongly related, but different since I can't undo my upvote without an edit: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10765/updating-an-out-of-date-answer-versus-keeping-author-intent

Comment: The stack exchange network makes it so you have **5 minuets** to undo an up-vote; but once vote has been changed, you cannot change it again.

Comment: @Alex: I'm very aware of this. My upvote was locked in *last year*. Since the answer is now *wrong* (it was originally correct), I want to reverse my upvote.

Comment: Anyhow, am I to assume by the downvotes that I have no options and we're stuck with a question that has a top-voted answer which is wrong? Awesome. I'm sure that's exactly how Stack Exchange is supposed to work.

Comment: it's a year old question, why are you upset?

Comment: @Alex: What does the question's age have to do with anything? If I were to ask the same question right now, it'd be marked as a duplicate. We're supposed to be curating answers so that they are a source of knowledge for other users that have similar questions. But, I have no tools to do so because any edits I could make would be rejected, and I don't even have the ability to downvote the answer because I previously upvoted it. I'm asking what I can do about this. If the answer is "nothing", then simply say so.

Comment: @Alex part of this site's modus operandi is the constant curation of the content presented here. We are not a forum where old content is left alone to slowly become out of date. @ Ellesedil - you should instead write an up to date answer, and leave a comment on the out of date answer

Comment: @Robotnik: I actually have an answer on the question already that I wrote last year, which I have since updated. I originally left a comment on the out of date answer, but then deleted it because I realized that the author of that answer isn't active and is unlikely to notice the notification. I guess the comment could help for those who come upon the question somehow. The only problem there is that my upvote is still stuck.

Comment: other users would still see the comment..

Comment: @Timelord64 yes, I thought I said that. I also then left a comment. I'd still like my upvote back, though.

Comment: Unfortunetly, at present your simply not entitle to it.

Answer (score 4):

Come on now. Editing in out of date disclaimers is about the only tool we have left to mark obsolete information, as a startling portion of the user base would rather simply let old, incorrect information stand, rather than actually caring about site curation and pruning them. I have edited in your disclaimer. It will probably get rolled back, because double standards, but feel free to reverse your up vote.

Comment: Thanks. I'm satisfied, even if it is rolled back. I simply wanted to correct the situation, but had no way to do so. It'd be nice if we could figure out an actual solution rather than waiting for a high rep user to come by and make an edit.

Comment: While I'm definitely not a fan of such a unilateral action, I'm not going to roll it back. Just register my disapproval of such an action when its under discussion.

Answer (score 1):

If an answer is out of date in a minor way (perhaps just a few underlying numbers have changed in a patch) just edit the new information in. If an answer is out of date in a major way - e.g. the mechanics discussed have been significantly changed or removed - then I see no problem with just making a new answer while pointing out that the other answer is out of date. I don't not being able to reverse a vote is worth making an edit that undermines the answer.